# related articles on post page

Tags: php

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_XXX, $XXX);
$result= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news"); 
$total = mysql_result($result, 0, 0); 

// create a random number 
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
$number = mt_rand()%$total; 

// get a random entry 
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news LIMIT $number, 5");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
?>
```

This is the PHP code I'm using and it pulls up random data from the table I want but I can't seem to figure out how to have it not show the current post it's on. Will I need to throw in an if statement in? If I do where would it go and how to impletment it. The only thing I can thing of is using if statements to check if the post_id on page matches the post_id posted. But I'm new to this and the only thing I can think of is. 
    if(!$row['post_id'] == $_GET['id']) {
    }
I don't know what to make it do after. Also if anyone knows how or can help point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Here is the update of the total thing here. It still shows post it's already on. hope this helps. This is the php code for the page.

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_xxx, $xxx);
$result= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news"); 
$total = mysql_result($result, 0, 0); 

// create a random number 
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
$number = mt_rand()%$total; 

// get a random entry 
$result= mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM news WHERE post_id <> %d LIMIT %d, 3", $post->post_id, $number)); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
?>

<?php
if (! isset($_GET['id']) || (int) $_GET['id'] === 0 ) {
echo "Incorrect input, aborting"; 
exit;  
} 
mysql_select_db($database_xxx, $xxx);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE post_id = " . $_GET['id'];
// a line of debug to make sure things are as expected

$query = MYSQL_QUERY($sql);
// query your table for a match with post_id
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == "1")
// if a record is found, show the info 
{ 
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query); // set $fetch to have the values from the table
} else { 
echo "No match in database found."; // if no match is found, display this error 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I think text in your question suggests you are already thinking in right direction, though you should follow @Matt's suggestion for `mysql_*` and [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code is on the page where you view the main product:

```
$result= mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id <> %d LIMIT %d, 5", $post->id, $number));
```

Also, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions anymore as they are deprecated; checkout [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it still shows current post in the related post. I had a question though...what is $post supposed to be? is the that $_GET['id'] ?

Comment: $post is the current post object. I just assumed that's what it was called as you don't mention anything about how the current post is called. I just noticed you are using $_GET['id'].. do you not request the post from the database at all?

Comment: i edited above if you can take a look at that would be great.